# Can you give me a good alternative to Rotman's Group Theory book?

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, soft-question

I've been trying to learn out of Rotman's book "An Introduction To The Theory of Groups" for the last few months, and it's rough going.  I've been studying Chapters 7, 10, and 11 in particular, and he's too wordy in many places and makes massive leaps of logic in others.  I can't seem to learn from him.

I understand that this is a seminal book on group theory, so I don't want to just toss it out the window, but I think I need to go somewhere else to actually learn advanced group theory and then just use Rotman as a reference.  I'd appreciate any help you can give!

Comment: I am not sure if Rotman written only one book on group theory.. It would be better if you can write the title or at least write which chapters do you feel difficult in understanding so that somebody can help you out... I would say for beginners, "Abstract Algebra" by "Dummit Foote" would be better for group theory..

Comment: Added the title, thanks.  I was thinking more along the lines of "second course" in group theory, as I already feel comfortable with the basics.

Comment: What kind of flavour of group theory are you after? Something on classical group theory? Infinite stuff? For example, the last couple of chapters of Rotman's book are expanded upon in the books of Magnus, Karrass and Solitar and of Lyndon and Schupp, both called *Combinatorial group theory*. John Meier has a good introductory book to the more modern approach to this subject area, entitled *Graphs, groups and trees: An Introduction to the Geometry of Infinite Groups*.

Comment: (Although both Magnus, Karrass and Solitar and Lyndon and Schupp are essential reading if you want to enter the world of infinite (discrete) groups. One of my friends first challenges as a PhD student was "find and correct the error on p7 (or something) of Lyndon and Schupp". They are both quite old, but really good. Magnus, Karrass and Solitar is the only reference for some things about free groups and its exercises are more than just a little impressive, while Lyndon and Schupp contains the 1970 incarnation of geometric group theory.)

Comment: Great stuff, thanks for the advice.  Combinatorial group theory is exactly what I think I need a better book for.  I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rotman's book is quite old fashioned. Why not try one of the following:

John S. Rose, *A Course on Group Theory*

Derek J.S. Robinson, *A Course in The Theory of Groups*

Marty Isaacs, *Finite Group Theory*.

Each of these books has a lot of good exercises!

Comment: Well, Rotman's book is perhaps not "quite old-fashioned", but just not a recent book. How would you name Bertram Huppert's books then ?

Comment: Depends on the edition of Rotman of course. You are absolutely right: it has been updated since 1965 several times. Still the approach is different from the books I mentioned above. Huppert's books are a different matter. I would not recommend this for an introduction - my version has the gothic capital notation for groups and capital notation for elements of a group ...

Comment: Yes, you are right. Huppert has "old" notation, but is still worth to read. For an introduction I would not consider it, too.

Comment: I found that Robinson's book was a bit too jumpy for my liking. It is excellent as a reference, but doesn't go very deeply into anything.